I am a plant. What is my name?
Note: I created this puzzle.
I am a plant from a certain game.
I missed my flight because a zombie blocked the aisle that leads to my seat, and an another zombie was sat on my reserved seat, although that zombie was later removed from the plane.
A few days from today, it will be solstice again, and because I was not wearing a cleat, my limbs (including it's fingers) got covered by the fall.
What is my name?
Hint:

 My name has 2 words.


 I was added to the game a few days before solstice.


I'm pretty sure this is the seasonal sounding...

 ...Missile Toe from the Plants vs. Zombies franchise - a weaponised mistletoe plant which when fully charged can send explosive chilling homing missiles at targeted squares in the playing grid. (The mentions of zombies in the flavour text provide a huge clue to the game(s) of interest here...)



The key to finding this 2-word name is extracting the true puzzle from the text:

 Focus solely on the words in bold. These are: missed aisle a removed limbs fingers. These lead us to the plant' name...

 - 'missed' provides the MISS portion;

 - 'aisle a removed' gives us (-a)isle (i.e. we remove the 'a' from 'aisle'), or ISLE;

 - 'limbs fingers' leads us to TOEs, i.e. the 'fingers' of the leg (a limb).

 (And yes, I am a regular player of this game, hence why this has jumped out at me...!)


I gotta say, I believe that this is the correct answer! (also hey, fellow PvZ player :D)
